# Cordova/Phonegap: Is the camera enabled?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can I figure out if the camera is enabled or disabled for my application (in the device's settings)?

My goal is to display a custom message in case the camera is disabled.

I am using Cordova/Phonegap 6.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "figure out if the camera is enabled or disabled for my application" you mean "is the camera authorized for use by my application" (as it's not possible to "disable" the camera on Android or iOS), you can use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to do this:

First install it:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

Then use it:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isCameraAuthorized(function(authorized){
    if(!authorized){
        // Display some message to user
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Comment: Dave, you are right: of course I should have written "authorized" instead of "enabled". Anyways: the plugin you mentioned  is exactly what I was looking for. And it works like a charm on iOS and newer Android phones. Unfortunately, Android 5 versions will always return "authorized==true". This is very well documented in the plugin's documentation ... and I was able to prove it myself with one of my test devices. But anyways: this is all I need and again: THANK YOU!